# Converting raw query to eloquent laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, backend

Relationships:

```
public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id');
    }

public function status() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Status::class, 'status_id');
    }
```

Query:

```
return DB::table('asset_management_system.assets')
        ->join('asset_management_system.categories', 'asset_management_system.assets.category_id', '=', 'asset_management_system.categories.id')
        ->select('asset_management_system.categories.name', 'asset_management_system.categories.icon')
        ->selectRaw('count(asset_management_system.assets.category_id) as count,
        sum(case when status_id = 1 then 1 else 0 end) AS assigned,
        sum(case when status_id = 2 then 1 else 0 end) AS "stored",
        sum(case when status_id = 3 then 1 else 0 end) AS missing,
        sum(case when status_id = 4 then 1 else 0 end) AS broken')
        ->groupBy('asset_management_system.assets.category_id')
        ->get();
```

This query currently returns a count of the assinged, stored, missing and broken assets for each category. How can I convert this to eloquent?

Comment: You can't. If you want an Eloquent object then you have to use Eloquent to make this happen. If you had any id's or unique values you could fetch the Eloquent objects based on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is totally fine. I believe that is the most performant approach.

Alternatively, you can you the [withCount](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) function.

I assume you already got your Category model:

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function assets()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Asset::class);
    }
}
```

```
$categories = Category::withCount([
    'assets',
    'assets as assigned_count' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('status_id', 1);
    },
    'assets as stored_count' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('status_id', 2);
    },
    'assets as missing_count' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('status_id', 3);
    },
    'assets as broken_count' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('status_id', 4);
    },
])
->get();
```

Then:

```
$categories->each(function ($category) {
    dump($category->assets_count);
    dump($category->assigned_count);
    dump($category->stored_count);
    dump($category->missing_count);
    dump($category->broken_count);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed.